# Snapshot of Failed pages in selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Is there any way to capture snapshot of the failed tests in selenium?. I need to use the code in my project for taking snapshots.Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Its possible in Selenium using getScreenShotAs Method. If you use the Testng then use TestListenerAdapter.
In Selenium:
You can write separate method for Screenshot.

File src = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.File);
FileUtils.copyFile(src,new File(D:\test.jpg");

Comment: Hi Vadivelan, I need only the failed page screenshots.

Comment: Whenever your script fail, then call screenshot method. My approach is when Assertion fail then we call screenshot method.

Comment: ok .Thanks vadivelan .I have 1 more doubt. Is it possible to highlight the issue field for eg if it is a drop down or text field. what we will get a full page with the failed issue or a page with failed field highlighted?

Comment: MultiScreenShot.jar provide screenshot for each element and after that you can use JavascriptExecutor to highlight the field.